# Error : extract() expects parameter 1 to be array null given in /home/beaufort/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/class-fire-utils.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, parameters

I updated my plugins and theme and now have this error on my site:

```
extract() expects parameter 1 to be array null given in /home/beaufort/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/class-fire-utils.php
```

Anyone know why? Or what I need to change to fix it?

The issue is on this line:

```
$global_layout                = apply_filters( 'tc_global_layout' , TC_init::$instance -> global_layout );
```

snippet below:

```
 /**
      * This function returns the layout (sidebar(s), or full width) to apply to a context
      *
      * @package Customizr
      * @since Customizr 1.0
      */
      function tc_get_current_screen_layout ( $post_id , $sidebar_or_class) {
          $__options                    = tc__f ( '__options' );

          global $post;

          //Article wrapper class definition
          $global_layout                = apply_filters( 'tc_global_layout' , TC_init::$instance -> global_layout );

          /* DEFAULT LAYOUTS */
          //get the global default layout
          $tc_sidebar_global_layout     = $__options['tc_sidebar_global_layout'];
          //get the post default layout
          $tc_sidebar_post_layout       = $__options['tc_sidebar_post_layout'];
          //get the page default layout
          $tc_sidebar_page_layout       = $__options['tc_sidebar_page_layout'];

          //what is the default layout we want to apply? By default we apply the global default layout
          $tc_sidebar_default_layout    = $tc_sidebar_global_layout;
          if ( is_single() )
            $tc_sidebar_default_layout  = $tc_sidebar_post_layout;
          if ( is_page() )
            $tc_sidebar_default_layout  = $tc_sidebar_page_layout;

          //builds the default layout option array including layout and article class
          $class_tab  = $global_layout[$tc_sidebar_default_layout];
          $class_tab  = $class_tab['content'];
          $tc_screen_layout             = array(
                      'sidebar' => $tc_sidebar_default_layout,
                      'class'   => $class_tab
          );

          //checks if the 'force default layout' option is checked and return the default layout before any specific layout
          $force_layout = $__options['tc_sidebar_force_layout'];
          if( $force_layout == 1) {
            $class_tab  = $global_layout[$tc_sidebar_global_layout];
            $class_tab  = $class_tab['content'];
            $tc_screen_layout = array(
              'sidebar' => $tc_sidebar_global_layout,
              'class'   => $class_tab
            );
            return $tc_screen_layout[$sidebar_or_class];
          }

          //The following lines set the post specific layout if any, and if not keeps the default layout previously defined
          $tc_specific_post_layout    = false;
          global $wp_query;
          //if we are displaying an attachement, we use the parent post/page layout
          if ( $post && 'attachment' == $post -> post_type ) {
            $tc_specific_post_layout  = esc_attr(get_post_meta( $post->post_parent , $key = 'layout_key' , $single = true ));
          }
          //for a singular post or page OR for the posts page
          elseif ( is_singular() || $wp_query -> is_posts_page ) {
            $tc_specific_post_layout  = esc_attr(get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'layout_key' , $single = true ));
          }

          //checks if we display home page, either posts or static page and apply the customizer option
          if( (is_home() && 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) || is_front_page()) {
             $tc_specific_post_layout = $__options['tc_front_layout'];
          }

          if( $tc_specific_post_layout ) {
              $class_tab  = $global_layout[$tc_specific_post_layout];
              $class_tab  = $class_tab['content'];
              $tc_screen_layout = array(
              'sidebar' => $tc_specific_post_layout,
              'class'   => $class_tab
            );
          }



        return apply_filters( 'tc_screen_layout' , $tc_screen_layout[$sidebar_or_class], $post_id , $sidebar_or_class );
      }
```

Comment: The error is not in this code! Where is your `extract()` call?

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 there is no extract() call in /home/beaufort/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/class-fire-utils.php. I just don't understand why I'm getting the error as I've never amended the code only updated the theme and plugins